# PostgreSQL: return select count(*) from table;

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

please help me with 1 more [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) question.

I have a PHP-script run as daily cronjob and deleting old records from 1 main table and few further tables referencing its "id" column:

```
create or replace function quincytrack_clean()
        returns integer as $BODY$
        begin
                create temp table old_ids 
                (id varchar(20)) on commit drop;

                insert into old_ids
                select id from quincytrack
                where age(QDATETIME) > interval '30 days';

                delete from hide_id where id in
                (select id from old_ids);

                delete from related_mks where id in
                (select id from old_ids);

                delete from related_cl where id in
                (select id from old_ids);

                delete from related_comment where id in
                (select id from old_ids);

                delete from quincytrack where id in
                (select id from old_ids);

                return select count(*) from old_ids;
        end;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

And here is how I call it from the PHP script:

```
$sth = $pg->prepare('select quincytrack_clean()');
$sth->execute();
if ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        printf("removed %u old rows\n", $row['count']);
```

Why do I get the following error?

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select" at character 9
QUERY:  SELECT  select count(*) from old_ids
CONTEXT:  SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function
"quincytrack_clean" near line 23
```

Thank you! Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RETURN (select count(*) from old_ids);
```